# kenetic js layer.find(); method return object

Tags: arrays, find, return, kineticjs

When invoking method:

```
var currentSelection = layer.find('#'+ layer.omniNodeSelected);
```

will the find method always return an array even if there is one node?

What would the best way to handle an array if there is only one element?

Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

`.find` will always return a Kinetic.Collection (a slightly extended javascript array).

That collection might be empty.

You still use .find even if there's only 1 element to return (as likely in your .find("#" example.

You can get the first element from the collection with currentSelection[0];